# Building kernel from RPM source package

Tags: linux-kernel, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I do the following on Fedora kernel src rpm :
(1) `rpm -ivh kernel-xxx.rpm`
(2) Go to `~/rpmbuild/SPECS` dir
(2) `rpmbuild -bp kernel.specs --nodeps`

then in the ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/ dir I get kernel-xxx dir 
where in there are two source dir -

(1) linux-xxx           <-------- A

(2) vanilla-xxx         <-------- B

Why are these two dir created - How do I use the configuration file 
/boot/config-xxx to build vmlinuz and initrd image ?

Which dir A or B sould I use for building ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel)? Step-by-step howto.